# VBA permutations of undetermined number of variables

Tags: algorithm, vba

Recently I am trying to get the permutation of undetermined number of variables. For undetermined I mean I was aiming to create an input box for users to put in the number.

Start from simple. Originally I was aiming to get a 4 digits permutations with each digit have different number of variables, i.e. 1st digit can only be A,B,C,D; 2nd digit be E,F; 3rd digit be G, H etc. Code are below:

```
Sub Permut()

Count = 1

For a = 1 To 4
For b = 1 To 2
For c = 1 To 2
For d = 1 To 2
For e = 1 To 2
'chr(97) is the alphabet "a"
Cells(Count, 1) = Chr(96 + a) & Chr(96 + Len(a) + b) & Chr(96 + Len(a) + Len(b) + c) & _
             Chr(96 + Len(a) + Len(b) + Len(c) + d) & Chr(96 + Len(a) + Len(b) + Len(c) + Len(d) + e)
Count = Count + 1
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next

End Sub
```

This will give you 64 different combinations without repetition.

Just wondering is there a way to generalize this process so that people can choose how many variables in total as well as within each digit?

Thank you.

Comment: That code is wrong: *Len(a)* will convert *a* to a *string* and count how many characters it has, which will always be 1. And this is true for all occurrences of *Len()* you have in your code; they are all always 1.

Comment: Thanks trincot. Should I use ubound() instead? but i guess it's not an array. Or maybe sth like max().

Comment: *UBound* only works on array variables, and for *max* you need two numbers. In your code you have to put the upper boundaries in variables, like `maxA = 4`, `maxB  = 2`, ... and then you woudl use these instead of `Len(a)`, ..etc. But see my answer for a generic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, where you would pass the *Permut* function the minimum value for each of the characters (digits) as one string, and the maximum characters also as a string. Both strings should have an equal number of characters of course:

```
Function Permut(min, max)
    Dim str, nxt, count

    str = min
    count = 1

    Do While str < max
        Cells(count, 1) = str 
        count = count + 1

        nxt = ""
        For i = Len(str) To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(str, i, 1) < Mid(max, i, 1) Then
                nxt = ChrW(AscW(Mid(str, i, 1))+1) & nxt
                Exit For
            End If
            nxt = Mid(min, i, 1) & nxt
        Next
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - Len(nxt)) & nxt
    Loop
    Cells(count, 1) = str 
End Sub
```

You would call it like this:

```
Permut "abc", "bcf"
```

That example would produce this list on your sheet:

> abc
>   abd
>   abe
>   abf
>   acc
>   acd
>   ace
>   acf
>   bbc
>   bbd
>   bbe
>   bbf
>   bcc
>   bcd
>   bce
>   bcf

#### How to Execute This with User Input and Button Click

If you want to call this code in response to an event, such as a button click, and want to pass it the contents of two cells where the user would first enter the *min* and *max* strings, then follow these steps:

1. Place an ActiveX command button on your sheet (put it somewhere in **D1** to leave room for some other stuff)
2. Double click it to generate the empty click event handler. If that does not work, go to the code window and select the name of the button from the drop-down at the top of the window, and select *Click* from the next drop down.
3. Complete the code of that event handler as follows (I assume the button is called *CommandButton1*, but don't change the generated name):

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Permut Range("B1"), Range("C1")
End Sub
```

This code assumes the user has to enter the *min* and *max* digits/characters in cells **B1** and **C1**. The **A** column is of course reserved for the output of the code.

For a more complete explanation on how to add a command button and attach code to its click event, read [*"Add a command button (ActiveX control)"* in the Office manual](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283#bmadd_or_edit_a_command_button__control).

Comment: s this a UDF? how to execute them?

Comment: I added some explanation on how to execute it with user input and button click.

Comment: Hi, just a minor point here. Maybe it's a dumb question but how do you set a cell(0,1) equal to sth. Not sure whether row 0 exist. I post a modification below in another answer.

Comment: Not dumb at all, thanks for mentioning it. I modified the code like you correctly suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

credit to the answer from trincot above.

I have tried to run the code with a bit modification coz I am not sure how to get set value into cells (0,1). It keeps saying error. But If I change the starting point to Cells(1,1) then I will miss the last permutation. So I just add an additional if statement to get the code work as I want.

```
Function Permut(min, max)
    Dim str, nxt, count

    str = min
    count = 1

    Do While str < max

        Cells(count, 1) = str
        count = count + 1

        nxt = ""
        For i = Len(str) To 1 Step -1

            If Mid(str, i, 1) < Mid(max, i, 1) Then

            'asc("a")=97; chr(97) ="a"
                nxt = Chr(AscW(Mid(str, i, 1)) + 1) & nxt
                Exit For
            End If
            nxt = Mid(min, i, 1) & nxt
        Next

        str = Left(str, Len(str) - Len(nxt)) & nxt

        If str = max Then

            Cells(count, 1) = str

        End If

    Loop

End Function
```